# How to make global environment variable programmatically in Airflow

Tags: airflow

I have a DAG like below:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator

def returnSum():
    BashOperator(task_id="running",
    bash_command="export value={var};".format(var=3))

with DAG(
    dag_id="test_python",
    schedule_interval=None,
    catchup=False,
    start_date=days_ago(1)) as dag:

    pyth=PythonOperator(
        task_id="read_from_aws_sm",
        python_callable=returnSum,
        provide_context=True
    )
    ba =  BashOperator(task_id="running_bash", bash_command="echo $value;")

    pyth >> ba
```

I am trying to set up an `environment` variable in the python method via `BashOperator` and attempting to access the value in another `BashOperator` but it gives me a blank output. How can I achieve this?